# How to change border thickness of UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I'm trying to make my search bar look like this 
[image]

A white background with a thin grey border.

On Xcode, I can set `Search style` to default (which gives the white background) and `Bar tint` to grey (which gives the grey border.)

But the result I get is this

[image]

How do I change the thickness of the bar to reflect the design I'm going for?

(also, is there a way to change just the font of the search bar? I only found ways to change the font size)

Comment: What you want is probably a combination of `setBackgroundImage(_:for:barMetrics:)` and `setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(_:for:)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Isn't that to set the background image? I'm just trying to change the thickness of the bar

Comment: @matt what size of images you prefer for SearchBar?

Comment: use the style minimal and set the translucent true

Answer (score 2):

Follow this below steps -

1.Choose `UITextField` from the object library

2.Drag to your storyboard

3.Choose border style as `none`.

4.Create a Swift file and add this below extension -

```
extension UIView {

   @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {

    get {

        return layer.cornerRadius

    }

    set {

        layer.cornerRadius = newValue

        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0

    }

}

   @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {

    get {

        return layer.borderWidth

    }

    set {

        layer.borderWidth = newValue

    }

}

   @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {

    get {

        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)

    }

    set {

        layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor

    }

  }

}



extension UIButton {

  func roundedButton(){

    let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,

                                 byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight],

                                 cornerRadii:CGSize(width:8.0, height:8.0))

    let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()

    maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds

    maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer1

  }

}

extension UITextField {

   func setLeftPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat){

    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))

    self.leftView = paddingView

    self.leftViewMode = .always
}

  func setRightPaddingPoints(_ amount:CGFloat) {
    let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.size.height))
    self.rightView = paddingView
    self.rightViewMode = .always
  }
}

extension UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {
    get {
        if let length = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyMaxLength) as? Int {
            return length
        } else {
            return Int.max
        }
    }
    set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kAssociationKeyMaxLength, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMaxLength), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

@objc func checkMaxLength(textField: UITextField) {
    guard let prospectiveText = self.text,
        prospectiveText.count > maxLength
        else {
            return
    }

    let selection = selectedTextRange

    let indexEndOfText = prospectiveText.index(prospectiveText.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)
    let substring = prospectiveText[..<indexEndOfText]
    text = String(substring)

    selectedTextRange = selection
  }
}
```

5.Now you can access this extensions either from storyboard or from code to change the values and see the effects.

6.You can change the corner radius, border width, border colour for `UITextField`.

Hope this method also helps.

Answer (score 0):

The style **UISearchBar.Style.minimal** provides no default background color or image

and use UITextFiled instead search bar so you can customise  icon location

```
YourTextFiled.rightView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "search-icon"))

YourTextFiled.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
```